# Steam Skyrim different languages on the same computer

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I and my brother are playing Skyrim from the same computer (using Family Sharing). The problem is that I prefer to play in English but he needs a localized version. There is the localized version in Steam, but each time I switch languages in Steam Skyrim settings, it downloads 3.5 GB of language files. It takes some time to download so have to wait each time before a game, and also I'm a bit worried about my SSD - it's additional 7 GB of writes each day.

So is there a way to not download it each time? I tried to save language files and replace them when needed, but Steam starts download anyway. And I have not found an option to disable auto-update. Maybe it's possible somehow to have 2 different installations of Skyrim from Steam on the same computer? Or have English voice with localized subtitles? That variant would suit us both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as the only possible solution (*for now, I hope*) is two Steam installations with the game in each one. Not ideal, requires double disk space, but at least you don't have to wait for download each time.

- Close Steam if it's running.
- Copy `Steam.exe` from your Steam folder (typically `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam`) into a new folder (for example, `C:\Games\Steam 2`).
- Launch `Steam.exe` from the new folder, it will download all other files and open your new Steam instance.
- Right click on the game in your library, `Properties` -> `Language` tab -> select your second language.
- Install the game as usual (*It may be possible to copy the game files from the first Steam installation, but I have not managed to make Steam to see the copied files, so the easiest way is to let Steam download the whole game again*).
- Ready! Now, if you need to play the game in the second language, just close Steam, launch `Steam.exe` from the new folder and start the game from the library.

Thanks @Jubatus and @Nitro.de for pointing me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't really find a solution it. You're not the only one though.
See [this steam community thread](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/828937546076055747/)
I also found a reddit thread where someone stated that he managed to download both version and run them.

Other suggested to try to download two instances of steam with both language and then run both games from there.

I'd suggest you try to install two steam instances in differente languages, and then install your skyrim in both folders ( or try to copy it and change settings ), so you might be able to run them in different languages.

I know it takes time to download-copy everything and it is annoying, but if it works once you've installed the games both times you don't have to wait everytime

Comment: I want to add the reason for the problem here, if you want you can add it to the answer. The auto audio download is an old error which seems not be fixed in the next years. The problem here is, that Steam always overrides Soundfiles if you change the Steam language, thats why it's not possible just to backup both language and paste them in if needed. If steam is e.g. in english and you switch to german steam is setting a language "flag" so steam dont care about the files you're using it just checks if the old flag is the same like the new one, if not -> override

Comment: What about using two different steam instance? If I'm not mistaken you can install steam in two different locaiton and set your library in mulitple places. So when you start steam with the "English" version it see the english skyrim in his library, while the the German steam version has its own german skyrim. Or do we have account issues? The idea is that if I run the second steam the language is already set in German and it doesnt ovveride it.

Comment: Again, there are only assumptions, I hope OP tries and then Edit's his post with the solution if he is successful

Comment: You can have 2 "installations" of steam of course. For steam you just need to copy the steam.exe anywhere else and start it, steam will download itself again in the new folder(same like you would donwload it from page) BUT all steam installations use the same path for their flags in the registry so you can have 1 million steam copys but every copy would use the same flags

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions! The problem solved by itself by now - my brother stopped playing Skyrim :) but anyway I tried (may be of use later again) - and it works! I will add a separate answer with details.

Comment: @Nitro.de Are these keys stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`?. If it's the later, the solution is what *everybody* should do when sharing a computer - make a separate user account for each user... It's kinda what the feature is for. (If it's the former, that's just lazy on Steam's part.)